# What is the difference between rendendered html shown in view page source and inspected by firebug?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, html

I am generating a pdf in iframe.In view page source there is no internal text of pdf, only iframe tag is shown

```
 <iframe id="Iframe1" src = "/demo/22.pdf" width='600' height='600' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But in firebug all text is shown and when i inspect a line inside pdf by firebug following in shown

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 122.072px; top: 404.603px; font-size: 13.1354px; font-family: serif; transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.997231, 1); transform-origin: 0% 0% 0px;" data-font-name="g_font_3" data-angle="0" data-canvas-width="125.85053914522952">What is a Heart Attack?</div>
```

Why internal html of a pdf is not shown in page source ? 
Is there is any way to get internal text of a pdf in the form as shown by firebug ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right iframe or ajax update will show only by inspected by firebug not in view page source becuase that are actually render after page load completed.

By capturing PDF document of html, you have to wait for iframe or Ajax update are load/ completed.

Comment: is there any way to get pdf's html after page load completed ?

Comment: you can 3rd party tool to generate PDF as used in past with this link http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToPdf.aspx. BTW you did not mentioned in your question what tool or technique to generate PDF from HTML.